# How do I do this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some messages and a current user.

Messages have an `id`, users have an `id`.

I want to get a list of (unique) user ids where:

The first user `id` is for the user who sent the message to the current user with the highest message `id`
and all the message ids for the last user id are lower than that of any other user who sent the current user a message.

So far I am able to get a list of users who sent the current user a message with:

```
"SELECT sender_id AS messgr_id FROM   messages 
    WHERE  receiver_id = '$curr_id' 
UNION SELECT receiver_id AS messgr_id FROM messages
    WHERE  sender_id = '$curr_id' ";
```

but I am stuck as to the best way to order it in the way i want (i am learning SQL as i do this and so im no expert :))

Thanks!

Comment: can you briefly explain your db schema?

Comment: What do you want as output? The ids of all users who sent to or received messages from current_user? Or just the 2 ids of the 2 users that sent the last message to and received the last message from current_user?

Comment: the ids of --all-- users...but list should be unique...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should do the trick

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT sender_id AS messgr_id FROM   messages 
        WHERE  receiver_id = '$curr_id' 
    UNION SELECT receiver_id AS messgr_id FROM messages
        WHERE  sender_id = '$curr_id'
) T1
GROUP BY messgr_id
ORDER BY messgr_id DESC
```

That will give you a list of *user ids* with duplicates eliminated, and sorted high-to-low.

---

**Update**:

Re-reading your question, it sounds like you're looking for a list of user id's ordered by *message* id -- which isn't currently shown in your example.  Assuming that your `messages` table has an `id` column (in addition to `receiver_id` and `sender_id`), here's how you would do that:

```
SELECT messgr_id, max(message_id) as max_message_id
FROM ( 
    SELECT sender_id AS messgr_id, id as message_id FROM messages 
        WHERE  receiver_id = '$curr_id' 
    UNION SELECT receiver_id AS messgr_id, id as message_id FROM messages
        WHERE  sender_id = '$curr_id'
) T1
GROUP BY messgr_id
ORDER BY max_message_id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks alot the Updated answer is likely what i am looking for...i could express in english but not in code...will try and accept soon as it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm are you sure selecting "id" in the inner select is good?...it seems like that will "split the union " into non-unique user ids because the message ids are different...

Comment: or does the group by messgr_id fix that?

Comment: you're correct on both points: adding `id` does split the union, but the `GROUP BY` eliminates the duplicates that result, while also allowing us to extract the max `message_id` for each user id.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but i think you only want to order your SELECTion?

```
"SELECT sender_id AS messgr_id FROM   messages 
    WHERE  receiver_id = '$curr_id'
    ORDER BY sender_id
UNION SELECT receiver_id AS messgr_id FROM messages
    WHERE  sender_id = '$curr_id' 
    ORDER BY sender_id DESC";
```

Comment: OP asked for no duplicates, which means either GROUP BY or DISTINCT would be part of the equation.

Comment: Actually - I stand corrected.  The UNION would take care of eliminating duplicates.